# add numbers between two given numbers?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to add the numbers between two given numbers. For example if the given numbers are 2 and 5, 2+3+4+5=14. The problem with my code is that I haven't set a, b and sum to anything but I don't what to set them to.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a, b, sum;
    printf("%d\n", a);
    printf("%d\n", b);
    scanf_s("%d", a);
    scanf_s("%d", b);
    for (int x = a; x <= b; x++) {
        sum += x;

    }
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    return sum;

}
```

Comment: Why not set them all to 0? `int a=0, b=0, sum=0;`?

Comment: `scanf_s("%d", a);` does not look good....

Comment: You can use `static int a, b, sum;` in order to initialize all variables to 0

Comment: @AntonH I did that however it did not work

Comment: @SouravGhosh Hadn't even looked at that, thought the issue would have been with `sum` not being initialised.

Comment: @KeineLust now that, being valid, may be unwanted, unless OP is aware of the actual effect.

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._

Comment: @SouravGhosh are you really saying you can't answer this question without more than just what is in the question?

Comment: @JeremyP It's not about what I (we) can or can not, it's about the question quality. As it is written, most of the effort would e guesswork and probably wasted, so, yes, I am not willing to answer. :)

Comment: Just do: `int a=0, b=0, sum=0;` whats the problem with that? And use `scanf` and ignore VS security bullshits

Comment: @SouravGhosh Turns out you were being wise in this case, I just got downvoted for giving a correct answer.

Comment: @JeremyP Been there, seen that. :( My two cents: Remove answer, VTC and move on (don't close the tab yet). Check back in sometimes and make further decision.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sum between 2 and 5 as per your example,

```
int a = 2;
int b = 5;

// Or for input from the user
scanf("%d",&a); // Note, for real you need to validate and do error handling
scanf("%d",&b); // Note, for real you need to validate and do error handling

int sum = 0;
```

`sum` always starts at 0.

`a` is the beginning of the loop, so you set it to the lower number.

`b` is the end of the loop, so you set it to the higher number.

Comment: Yeah but I want it for any given input!

Comment: `scanf("%d",&a);` and so on should help

Comment: Not my downvote, just want to reiterate the comment I mentioned under the question, probably it's going to be waste. I appreciate your effort to help the OP, but it seems OP needs some self-help first.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you make sure you understand what the printf and scanf_s functions do. Then look at what happens when execute the program, and compare that to the program you wrote. You need to be able to understand exactly why the program does what it does.

Once you know why your program does what it does, you can start to figure out how to change it to do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well I noticed what was wrong, here is the corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a, b, sum = 0;
    printf("insert num 1\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &a);
    printf("insert num 2\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &b);
    if (a < b) {
        for (int x = a; x <= b; x++) {
            sum += x;

        }
        printf("%d \n", sum);


    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know a loop is unnecessary for summing a range of consecutive numbers? `sum = ((b - a + 1) * (a + b)) / 2;` when a <= b.